# how to return method with Ienumerable

Tags: .net-core

hello there i have **domainmodel** like this:

```
 public string ComponentTitle { get; private set; }
    
 public string componentLatinTitle { get; private set; }
```

and this is my **dto**:

```
 public bool IsShow { get; set; }
  
 public string ComponentTitle { get; set; }
```

now i Want To return my dto and map the domain with dto in GetMethod, This is my ***Controller***:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<StaticComponentDto>> GetStaticComponents()
    {
        return await _staticComponent.GetComponents();
    }
```

and this is my service:

```
 public Task<IEnumerable<StaticComponentDto>> GetComponents()
        {
            var components =  _repository.Query().GetAllAsync();
            return new StaticComponentDto()
            {
                ComponentTitle = components.ComponentTitle;
            };
        }
```

my service didnt work :

and i have a error like this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Task<IEnumerable<StaticComponent>>' does not contain a definition for 'ComponentTitle' and no accessible extension method 'ComponentTitle' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<IEnumerable<StaticComponent>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    IM.Application
```

help me to implement my service or if it have a document to implement services or methods i'll be happy to learn thank you

Comment: You're getting all the `Components` from repository in your `components` variable. When you're returning a new `StaticComponentDto`, which of the `components` are you referring to? How does C# know?

If you want to map all the `components` you need to map every object in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting all the `StaticComponents` from repository in your `components` variable. When you're returning a new `StaticComponentDto`, which of the components are you referring to? How does C# know? you need to specify.

There are a number of ways you can map all the objects, one of them is:

You can iterate through the `components` and map them into a new `IEnumerable<StaticComponentDto>`.

```
var components = await _repository.Query().GetAllAsync();
var componentsDto = new List<StaticComponentDto>();
foreach (var component in components)
{
    var componentDto = new StaticComponentDto();
    componentDto.ComponentTitle = component.ComponentTitle;
    componentsDto.Add(componentDto);
}
return componentsDto;
```

Note:

- Also, if you are making asynchronous calls to asynchronous methods (in your case, you're calling the asynchronous repository method - `GetAllAsync()`), you should make your service method as async. Which means, you add the async keyword in the GetComponents() signature:
  `public async Task<IEnumerable<StaticComponentDto>> GetComponents()`
- Notice how in this case, we need to **await** the call from repository.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to return with linq select function:

```cs
return components.Select(component => new StaticComponentDto()
{
    ComponentTitle = component.ComponentTitle
});
```